# Calculate area of polygon recursively

Tags: matlab

I had to calculate any polygon given cordinates of point in 'x-vector','y-vector' (only thing I know is the cordinates are ordered clockwise and polygons like hourglass are not included). 
I tried writing this code:

```
function [areaofit] = Polygarea(xs,ys,cor,prevsum)
  if(length(xs)~=length(ys))
    disp('dimentions error!please try again');
  end
  if(nargin==2)
    cor=1;
    prevsum=0;
  end
  if(cor==length(xs)-1)
    areaofit=prevsum;
    figure(1);
    fill(xs,ys,'r');   
    title(['Area = ' num2str(areaofit)]);
  end
  if(cor~=length(xs)-1)
    mat=[xs(1) ys(1) 1;zeros(2,3)];
    for k=2:3
      mat(k,1)=xs(cor+k-1);
      mat(k,2)=ys(cor+k-1);
      mat(k,3)=1;
    end
    farea=prevsum+abs(det(mat))/2;
    Polygarea(xs,ys,cor+1,farea);
  end
```

The function does work with any convex polygon but there are concave polygons it does work with (like 'stars' e.g [image]). What can be improved in my solution? thanks

Comment: Do you also want to be able to calculate the of concave polygons? It is not clear (at least to me) what do you want more. If you need concave polygons you can triangulate..

Comment: Moreover, it looks to me that you have just a recursive call, isn't it? It is always true that any recursive relation can be written in iterative terms; this is especially true when you have just one recursive call. An iterative algorithm will be definitely more efficient here.

Comment: If it was not clear (as my nickname says I'm not a proffestional) the mission is caluclating only by recursive calls (not iterative since the practitioner gave assignment about recursive calls). The function has to be able to calculate area of every polygon (both concave polygons and convex polygons) with n cordinates (n is a netural finite number bigger than 2).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to modify this line:

```
farea=prevsum+abs(det(mat))/2;
```

to

```
farea=prevsum+det(mat)/2;
```

Like this, the concavities in your polygon will add or subtract areas according to what direction they sweep the 0..2π range. To ensure final positive values for your area, there should be something like `areaofit=abs(prevsum);`

Comment: Well, the analytic formula for the area of a triangle "contains" the order of scanning the corners. If you put the triangle corners in counter-clockwise order in your matrix, the area will e positive, otherwise it will be negative. Now, if you look at your concave polygon, the "full" -- i.e. convex -- corners are always in counter-clockwise order, and the "empty"-- i.e. concave -- corners are clockwise. Like this you subtract from the area of the convex hull all the concave holes.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. I'm not sure that the 'concave corners' are put in counter-clockwise order but futhermore why the area of clockwise corners is positive and counter-clockwise corners is negative? thank you again :)

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner Well, from geometric point of view, if you interchange 2 points out of three, the order or "scanning" them reverses. Now, from the algebraic point of view, if you interchange the 2 lines corresponding to your points into your matrix (the one that computes the area for you), the sign of the determinant changes also. This is important, because the order of your point in the polygon matters: if you go from F to H first, and then to G, you'll get a completely different polygon, but with the same points. To account for the order of points in polygon, we add directly the det.